# Serial port from PC not reaching the MCU

Tags: stm32, uart, serial

I'm trying to send some data from the PC to my STM32L432KC Nucleo board using UART.

Transmitting data to the PC works just fine, I'm receiving data through the STLink Virtual COM Port which I can see using any Serial Monitor like TeraTerm or others.

The problem is with RECEIVING the data from the PC. I've tried sending data using TeraTerm and Hercules and I also checked with Serial Data Monitor if the data is being sent and it looks like it is. But nothing shows up on the UART RX pin (checked with an oscilloscope)

For clarity - I'm not posting any code because the signal doesn't even reach the RX pin so it's not a problem with processing that data.

My process:

1. Connect the board to PC:

[image]

2. Board configuration in CubeMX:

[image]
[image]

3. Sending data through COM3 using TeraTerm or Hercules software:

[image]

As I click "send" I'm checking with an oscilloscope if anything shows up on pin A2(PA3) (which is the UART RX pin) - nothing shows up there

Additional info: Sending data from the board to the board works just fine. The problem is with PC->Board

Comment: Which MCU board with L432KC? A Nucleo? How is the PA3 pin configured?

Comment: Yeah, a Nucleo board. You can see the configuration on the screenshot. It's configured by CubeMX.

Comment: If it's not reaching the board, maybe you need a longer cable?

Comment: haha very funny.

Comment: Is there any IC between your computer and the Board? an Ft232rl that translates USB to Uart?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly the Nucleo board translates the data from USB to UART, I couldn't find information regarding that so I don't know

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios That question does not apply. The question describes it's a Nucleo board with embedded ST link serving as UART.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong pin.

The manual for Nucleo with L432KC says UART RX is PA15.

Comment: Alright, I've just checked, and turns out you were absolutely correct. Thank you very much for saving me from wasting even more hours looking for such a simple problem. Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Disconnect the board from your PC.

Open Teraterm at 9600 bps and hit a keyboard key repeatedly.

With a scope, probe pin D+ or D- of your USB connector.

Comment: That's impossible. The board is what contains the USB to serial adapter.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sending data through USB not RS-232

Comment: @EnricoMigliore Do you seriously suggest that disconnecting USB cable from board and then scoping D+ and D- will do anything to solve this? It does not explain how doing that will answer the question.

Comment: Justme answered the question.